# Enable Java sha1 raw mode like php sha1

Tags: java, php, binary, sha

I get a problem with php.sha1 and my java code.
My php code

```
echo base64_encode(sha1("test", TRUE));
qUqP5cyxm6YcTAhz05Hph5gvu9M=
```

And my java code is:

```
 static String Hash(String input) throws Exception {

    MessageDigest mDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
    byte[] result = mDigest.digest(input.getBytes());
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
       sb.append((result[i / Byte.SIZE] << i % Byte.SIZE & 0x80) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    }
    return base64_encode(sb.toString());

}
```

output `MTAxMDEwMDEwMTAwMTAxMDEwMDA=`

How should I change the loop to get equal strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should works like RAW SHA-1

```
String base64 = 
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(MessageDigest.
getInstance("SHA-1").digest(s.getBytes("ISO-8859-1")));
```